# Github action serve built artefact in apt repository

Tags: github-actions

I am currently using github actions to build a package nightly. This produces a .deb file as an artifact. Now I would like to automatically generate a github page that has the layout of an apt repository. I.e., so that I can add my github page to my /etc/apt/sources.list.d/myrepo.list
and then easily install the nightly built artifact.

Is this possible? How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to checking https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-pages-apt-repo - "This action will setup and manage a simple APT repo on your github pages".